# Failed to enable code coverage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of null

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops

I have an Azure pipeline building a spring boot Java service. I'm trying to enable code coverage, but I get a warning in the build log that no code coverage is generated:

```
Starting: Build
==============================================================================
Task         : Maven
Description  : Build, test, and deploy with Apache Maven
Version      : 3.183.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven
==============================================================================
##[warning]Failed to enable code coverage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of null
```

See the build step below. It completes successfully with the exception of above warning.

```
  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'myApp/pom.xml'
      goals: 'package'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      codeCoverageToolOption: cobertura
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
```

Based on the warning I assumed it needed the Corbertura plugin so added that to the pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>aaa.bb.ccc.dd</groupId>
      <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>apiservice</artifactId>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Based API-Service</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>MyOrg</name>
        <url>https://www.myorg.com</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>    
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot-starter-parent.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>            
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>               
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>   
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                    <report>cobertura</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
                </reportSets>               
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Still no success. I'd really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share us your full pom.xml file? Could you please try to run your maven build in your local machine and make sure the maven build is working well. On my side, I use this demo pom.xml and on my test project, it work well. You can use the  different reports in the following  doc: http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I have added the full pom.xml. Note that the build works just fine. It is only the code coverage that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Could you please try to run the maven build in your local machine and check if the code coverage report will work well on your local?

Comment: Thanks @KevinLu-MSFT Will do. My local env is not setup to run maven builds, but I will work with the developers.